# Finding unique elements between two 2 TSV Files

Tags: java, collections

Hi guys I am stuck with one of my problem assignments. I have tried different approaches but I'm still not able to do it.

Comment: Let's start by hearing your approaches, and why they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the trick. Process the old file first, then overwrite existing ones from the new file.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

...

public class ContactsProcessor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> contactsNew = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("contactsNew.tsv"));
        List<String> contactsOld = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("contactsOld.tsv"));
        List<String> contactsGmail = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String, String> gmailMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // process old contacts first -- add to a Map
        for (String info : contactsOld) {
            String[] parts = info.split("\\t");
            if (info.endsWith("@gmail.com")) {
                gmailMap.put(parts[0], info);
            }
        }
        // process new contacts second -- add to a Map, overwriting old contacts with same name
        for (String info : contactsNew) {
            String[] parts = info.split("\\t");
            if (info.endsWith("@gmail.com")) {
                gmailMap.put(parts[0], info);
            }
        }
        contactsGmail.addAll(gmailMap.values());
        Collections.sort(contactsGmail);

        Files.write(Paths.get("contactsGmail.tsv"), contactsGmail);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. but    gmailMap.put(parts[2], info) is throwing arrayindexoutofbound exception

Comment: Actually rahul, that might be a problem with your input. If one of the things between the tabs was empty, it would cause the list to shrink and an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException would occur.

Comment: I appreciate your help guys. but the above approach still writes duplicate contents

Comment: I re-read your question and updated my answer to use the name as the key in the Map and sort the resulting List before writing it to a file.